# Upload Google sheets JSON feed to FTP server on a daily basis

Tags: python, json, google-apps-script, scheduled-tasks

I need a simple script to upload my google sheets JSON feed to ftp server on a daily basis.

I am planning to use Python and Task Scheduler, but I am looking for another solution. Maybe it is possible with Google Apps Script.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Lasha Dolenjashvili,

This is not possible with Google Apps Script.
To make outbound `FTP` requests from `Google Apps Script` there is a similar restriction from App Engine as well. You are alternatives are unless to find an HTTP interface to the server, some sites offer both HTTP and FTP.
You can check the log [Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/bookmark-groups/78025)